# Cassandra best practice to ORDER BY using PRIMARY KEY

Tags: database, cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0

Originally I had a cassandra table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
open_time timestamp, 
open double, 
close double, 
high double, 
low double, 
volume bigint, 
PRIMARY KEY(open_time));



open_time                       | close  | high   | low   | open   | volume
---------------------------------+--------+--------+-------+--------+--------
 2020-08-05 06:00:00.000000+0000 | 181.53 | 184.32 | 181.1 | 184.32 |    100
 2020-08-04 06:00:00.000000+0000 | 181.53 | 184.32 | 181.1 | 184.32 |    100
```

I need to perform a query to get the latest open_time. After noticing that querys like

```
SELECT open_time FROM table ORDER BY open_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

are not allowed, I wonder what's the best practice here.

My idea is to add an id column, that I can use **open_time** as clustering order. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
id int,
open_time timestamp, 
open double, 
close double, 
high double, 
low double, 
volume bigint, 
PRIMARY KEY(id, open_time)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (open_time DESC);
```

Is this a valid solution to get the job done or are there better ways, e.g. something without an extra id column, because I would never query over the id itslef.

The most queries would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE open_time >= '2013-01-01 00:00:00+0200' AND  open_time <= '2013-08-13 23:59:00+0200';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLUSTERING ORDER` enforces the on-disk sort order within each partition.  So ordering by the same key that you're partitioning on isn't possible.  Partitioning by `id` will face a similar challenge, in that the `CLUSTERING ORDER BY open_time` will only be enforced *within* each `id`.

> I wonder what's the best practice here.

Models like these are usually solved by time bucketing, as I mentioned in an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63344619/structuring-cassandra-table-for-date-queries) earlier today.  To select the best "bucket," you'll need to understand your business case like number of entries per day, as well as the query requirements.

For the sake of example, let's say that month would work the best.  If each row contained a value of 'YEAR-MONTH', the PK definition would look like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (month_bucket,open_time))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (open_time DESC);
```

Then, you could support a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE month_bucket = '2013-08'
  AND open_time >= '2013-08-01 00:00:00+0200' AND  open_time <= '2013-08-13 23:59:00+0200';
```

Likewise, querying the most recent entry would only require the most recent (current?) month as a parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE month_bucket = '2020-08'
LIMIT 1;
```

As the results are stored within each `month_bucket` sorted by `open_time` in descending order, that query would return the most-recent entry.

I wrote an article on this for DataStax (several years ago) which is relevant to this problem.  It's been moved to a new part of their site, which hosed the formatting, but the content is defintely there.  Give it a read; hope it helps: [We Shall Have Order!](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2015/03/we-shall-have-order)

Answer (score 1):

If id is mentioned as primary key, it must be included in where clause otherwise it would need allow filtering.
You can try querying with "Select max(open_time)....",otherwise you can use id as above which will be incremented with every record and a result, id with highest value will always have the latest record.